# Accessing variable across different phtml file in magento

Tags: php, magento

i want to defer javascript files form magneto `head.phtml` file, the scripts and css are called by the  `$this->getCssJsHtml();` function in magneto head.phtml file so is just simple substr the output like

```
$str  =  $this->getCssJsHtml();
$css  =  substr($str, 0, strpos($str, "<script"));
$js   =  substr($str,strpos($str, "<script") );
```

then i save the $js to registry like

```
Mage::register('hs_scripts'  ,  $js);
```

and in the `footer.phtml` i call it from the registry like

```
echo Mage::registry("hs_scripts");
```

now **every thing work well unless i enable the magneto cache** , and when i enable the magneto cache and then open let say homepage then, on every next page only the homepage scripts get loaded,

if i disable the cache, everything work, so i need a way to store data form 1 phtml file and then access it on other file

Comment: I don't think everything will work well with footer. Footer block get cached and you will get same content on every page.

Comment: so what can i do sir ??

Comment: i also tried to store the data in the static variable of a helper, but it didn't work either

Comment: I suggest to not use defer. Just enable js/css merge and use some extension to compress them.

Comment: thanks for telling me that, it is the footer that is being cached every time, this help me to find this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63259/do-not-cache-footer and im able to solve the problem

Comment: That is sounds good you are able to solve your problem, but restricting block from being cached is not best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead adding your scripts to footer block, which gets cached, try creating new block and adding it to `before_body_end` block.

*[theme]/layout/local.xml* file:

```
<default>
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/template" name="footer.scripts" template="page/html/footer/scripts.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

*[theme]/template/page/html/footer/scripts.phtml* file:

```
echo Mage::registry('hs_scripts');
```

Best of luck!